# How do I add a number to the launcher icon like HTC mail Does?

Tags: android, icons

Does anyone know how to accomplish adding to my application's launcher icon the circular badge with a number inside of it (indicating number of unread emails) like the HTC mail application does?  I know how to do this for notifications, but not for the launcher icon.

To clarify, it's **not** a widget, but an application icon.

Comment: That isn't a default Android behavior (if you are talking about adding a number like unread to the icon).. Does the rom you are running have custom chrome like sense ui, or motoblur?

Comment: It doesn't do that on my N1 (CM6), and I don't think it would be possible anyway, icons are hard-baked into the app, I've never seen any way of changing it dynamically. Are you sure it isn't a widget?

Comment: First, I'm using the HTC EVO 4g with Android 2.2, so it does have some UI customization.  Second, I apologize, I thought gmail's icon did it too, only HTC's mail icon does this.  I'm fairly sure it's not a widget, unless there's some way to fake out the OS to insert a widget when the user inserts an app shortcut on the desktop.  Regardless, the icon-sized "widget" isn't even available in the HTC mail widget list.  So I guess the answer is that this is custom behavior that would be painful to implement, yes?

Comment: It sounds like custom behavior that HTC has hacked into the OS

Comment: HTC might even ship their own built OS - I know Garmin does (did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting Daenyth's answer so I can mark this as answered:

@glenviewjeff: It sounds like custom behavior that HTC has hacked into the OS [launcher].

Comment: Both HTC and Samsung have added this custom behaviour: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864184/how-do-i-set-up-htc-sense-and-samsung-touchwiz-app-icon-badges/14055329]

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a widget, not an icon. Icons are static. You can find out more info here: [Introducing home screen widgets and the AppWidget framework](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but please see my response above; it's not a widget.