# How to get a notification in the corner of program icon?

Tags: android, push-notification, icons

**[image: How to get a red Badge Notifications on Android like ios style]**

For Example: 
 Notification like facebook, missed call and new message notification.
 I have attached sample screen shot here.

Comment: Just a simple guess, on receiving of notification, just change the icon :)

Comment: what your actual requirement for that?

Comment: why you dot google this ?

Comment: you can archive this using `Application Widget Provider`.

Comment: @Simple Plan can you please explain how to achieve this using application provider?

Comment: @Kedarnath can u please explain how i change the icon depends on my notification count dynamically?

Comment: I just gave you to idea, I dont know if it is possible to change application icon programmatically or not.

Answer (score 6):

There is no general way for that, I guess there are some private extensions of the manufacturers. So you could dig for that device specific APIs, but they could been private too, better drop that idea.

**Update:** However for samsung devices is there a solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20136484/995926).

Answer (score 0):

In android, we don't have badge style approach as iOS but some manufactures are supporting to display badge on app icons.

[Example for badge style icon on app in android](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/07/android-ios-style-badge-app-icon-for.html)

### Samsung , sony and HTC supports adding badge to the app icon.

Samsung:

```
ContentResolver localContentResolver = this.a.getContentResolver();
Uri localUri = Uri.parse("content://com.sec.badge/apps");

ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
localContentValues.put("package", PACKAGE NAME);
localContentValues.put("class", CLASS NAME);
localContentValues.put("badgecount", number);

update localContentResolver, if update fails then localContentResolver.insert(localUri, localContentValues);
```

---

For Sony

```
Intent intent= new Intent("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");

intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", Class Name);

intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", true);

intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE",number);

intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", packageName);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

for HTC:

```
Intent updateIntent = new Intent("com.htc.launcher.action.UPDATE_SHORTCUT");
updateIntent.putExtra("packagename", packageName);
updateIntent.putExtra("count", number);
this.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);

Intent setNotificationIntent = new Intent("com.htc.launcher.action.SET_NOTIFICATION");
ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
setNotificationIntent.putExtra("com.htc.launcher.extra.COMPONENT", localComponentName.flattenToShortString());
setNotificationIntent.putExtra("com.htc.launcher.extra.COUNT", number);
this.sendBroadcast(setNotificationIntent);
```