# Samsungs TouchWiz BadgeProvider

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, badge, samsung-touchwiz

Is there any documentation about the BadgeProvider? 
Many Apps use it, but I didn't find any documentation about it...

Regards Sebi2020

Comment: Solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136483/how-do-you-interface-with-badgeprovider-on-samsung-phones-to-add-a-count-to-the/20136484#20136484

Comment: But the question wasn't how to do that, but where the documentation can be found.