# Clear badge count on clearing app cache

Tags: android, badge

I need to show badge count on the app icon. After some research I have found a shortcut badge library for it. The library is really very good and working fine in almost all the listed devices which it's used.

But in Samsung Edge 7, it's creating a problem for me.

**Problem:**

The badge from app icon does not get updated or cleared. I have uninstall the app as well as clear the app cache from the application manager. But still it gets persisted in the same state.

**Link of library:** https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line in manifest file. This worked from me :-

```
<meta-data android:name="me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger" android:value="DISABLE" />
```

OR

use this link :-

[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055413/how-to-clear-count-badge-after-clearing-data-and-uninstall-application-in-androi)