# Not showing notification in Android o even after implementing Channel

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am facing some problem with Notification in Android - O.
I am trying to display Notification in android O. Some how my app is not 
displaying any notification even after using a notification channel.

My is [here](https://github.com/KaustubhMemane/NotifyMe/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kmema/android/notifyme/MainActivity.java)

Any suggestion or help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification not showing in Android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-o)

Comment: tried it. I have already created a channel as mentioned in Documentation. It is working fine in the previous version of Android but not in Android-O.

Comment: @DivySoni According to documentation we are supposed to use  NotificationCompat.Builder(Context, String) because  NotificationCompat.Builder (Context context)
constructor was deprecated in API level 26.0.0. but the android studio is showing me an incorrect argument error

Comment: Notification.Builder build = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("You have been notify")
                .setContentText("This is your Notifiaction Text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent); 
this is working fine


 @DivySoni i guess it supposed to be Notification.Builder(Context context, String ChannelID)