# What do I need to do exactly to use NotificationCompat with NotificationChannel?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

I've seen in the Android documentation and other sites (including this one) that it's possible to create a channel and use NotificationCompat but I'm not getting it. I'm about to go crazy trying to make this work.

Using `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat` or `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`
Android Studio show: "Builder(Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (Context, String)"

```
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, idNoti);// here
```

It does not even show me a deprecation message of NotificationCompat if I only use Builder(Context).

My **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    ...
}
```

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio (2.3.3) on a Mac.
I need to use NotificationCompat.

Comment: Check out this : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels/

Comment: `26.0.0-alpha1` *is* old - you should be on `26.0.2` at this point. You shouldn't be using `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat` at all - it has been deprecated.

Comment: @ianhanniballake And how am I supposed to do that? I see everything updated from the sdk manager /:

Comment: @ianhanniballake Even on windows with the latest version of Android studio. I have everything updated.

Comment: @user5195185 - they aren't in the SDK Manager anymore: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: @ianhanniballake Nothing changed /: I can only use 26.0.0-alpha1. Why?

Comment: you need to add repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}

take a look https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: @humazed Yes, I did.

Comment: @ianhanniballake but maybe I need to uninstall support repository from the SDK Manager to make this work?

Comment: no, you don't, what exactly is the problem, you don't need to update the support lib for notification to work

Comment: Got it! (uninstalling the support repository from the SDK Manager)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-8-oreo

Answer (score -1):

you need first to create a channel from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534559/3998402)

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

      /* Create or update. */ 
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
          "Channel human readable title",  
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
      mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }
```

and then hook your notification to it.

`notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel_01");`

for more info see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGIw4MIJn5o) from Android Developers