# Cannot find method createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel)

Tags: android

I'm trying to handle notification with Android Oreo (SDK 27).

Here is my code creating the NotificationChannel:

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
// .. building mChannel, the NotificationChannel instance
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

Android Studio tells this

```
Error:(67, 32) error: cannot find symbol method createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel)
```

I've a dependency on support-compat:27.0.0 set into my core/build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `createNotificationChannel()` method on `NotificationManagerCompat`. You have to use the native `NotificationManager` for that.

**UPDATE 2019-07-29**: As [Onkar Nene points out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5255021/onkar-nene), they finally added `createNotificationChannel()` on `NotificationManagerCompat`. Use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01` or newer.

Comment: True ! Thanks; I was misled by the accepted answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192859/android-notification-doesnt-appear

Comment: @matdev: I am hoping that they eventually update `NotificationManagerCompat`, so perhaps in the future, that answer will be correct.

Comment: A bit sad that the official docs suggest to use `NotificationManagerCompat` here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Priority

Comment: Android documentation is a bit sad all over the place. :/

Comment: Wow so the official Android documentation is incorrect. That's great.

Comment: Welcome to Android development! :D

Comment: Seriously though, please explain how to create a native NotificationManager, @CommonsWare

Comment: @AndrewKoster: Call `getSystemService()` on a `Context`. Where you get the `Context` from varies widely, based on where you are trying to raise the `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a completely different syntax and namespace from the NotificationManagerCompat example above, so it's a useful example now that the NotificationManagerCompat class is incompatible with Android 9's notification channels.

Comment: Now with `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01` you can use `NotificationManagerCompat.createNotificationChannel()` for API 26+.