# FCM Messages not appearing in the status bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the FCM docs on setting up the Android app for receiving FCM notifications.
My `app` `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "np.com.ravi.fcmtest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//for firebase notifications
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

//for firebase notifications
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my project level `build.gradle` is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //for firebase notifications
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have a MainActivity that has basically no code

I have two services as:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}
}
```

And

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification message deleted");
}

@Override
public void onSendError(String s, Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    //createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    // Create Notification
    Log.d("On", "createNotification");

    //for when the notification is tapped we are directed to the MainActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    //setting notification attributes
    Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //post notification to notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
}
```

I have also registered the two services in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

     for firebase messaging service
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I should be getting the firebase notifications. But I am not receiving any messages in my LogCat. I am also not getting them in my status bar as notifications regardless of whether my app is in the foreground or the background.

The messages I am receiving in my Logcat are:

```
12-14 12:40:46.140 32287-32287/np.com.ravi.fcmtest D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
12-14 12:40:46.218 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 78587
12-14 12:40:46.220 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Using measurement service
12-14 12:40:46.220 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-14 12:40:46.224 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Activity paused, time: 949735552
12-14 12:40:46.234 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-14 12:40:46.240 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=78587, _sc=MainActivity, _si=-8670171141235923720}]
12-14 12:40:46.269 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Using measurement service
12-14 12:40:46.269 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-14 12:40:46.270 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-14 12:40:46.270 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
12-14 12:40:51.313 32287-2094/np.com.ravi.fcmtest V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Please help me get through this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you debug the code ? Did onMessageReceived called for each notification?

Comment: Which device are you testing on?

Comment: @ravi please check my ans and update your gradle.

Comment: @AswinPAshok I am testing on OnePlus 3T

Comment: @Guruji I added the dependency for firebase core and still no luck. I am using Firebase console to send messages BTW. The console says that the messages are sent, but I have no luck catching them on the Log.

Comment: do you get notification when app is in foreground?

Comment: @Guruji I received the message in the log. Thanks. But the notification is not being generated. Do you know why?

Comment: @AswinPAshok I added the firebase core dependency, the fcm message did show up on my log while the app was in foreground. But not in the status bar as notification.

Comment: try this. In Settings Menu go to Battery settings and disabled Aggressive doze & App Hibernation. I got it from a one plus forum. Worth a shot

Comment: @AswinPAshok There is no such thing in my Battery Settings. https://postimg.org/image/xee1cowxd/

Comment: Do you have notification issues on other apps? Which OS are you on?

Comment: @AswinPAshok Nope, none at all. In fact I have another app that I wrote that generates different types of Notifications (inbox style, picture style and so on) on Button click which works fine.

Comment: your os? Factory OS or custom ROM?

Comment: @Guruji I am getting `Processing queued up service tasks: 2` in my LogCat. What does that mean?

Comment: @AswinPAshok Oxygen OS, Android Oreo. Factory OS.

Comment: Try that in some other phone, or an emulator. OP3T seems to have some [issues with push notifications](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/no-notifications.478745/)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-8-oreo). It may help

Comment: @AswinPAshok Thank you very much. I tested it on my friend's phone and it worked. I am disappointed with my phone for the first time. Can you suggest any workaround with this problem?

Comment: @ravi Happy to help you.Happy coding.

Comment: If it is not an oxygenos bug, there should be a settings somewhere to fix it. Check the Battery Optimization settings under battery settings. Look for aggressive doze, autostart manager or something like that. **Test it on some other OREO device.** If it is not working on any oreo device, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-8-oreo  From your code, it seems you have'nt used [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html) which is essential to show notifications in oreo..

Comment: Go here : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0.html
And read what changed in notification API

Answer (score 0):

you can add **firebase-core** must be to get firebase notification and message. in your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

Comment: @ravi  Processing queued up service tasks: 2 you can try restart your device or check in other device or other phone, or an emulator.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
}
```

Write this line and check notification data is getting