# error when use fcm notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

I want send notification from server and panel firebase,i want when send push notification from panel firebase and click notification open url and send push from server open app but when send push from panel firebase app is force close,how to can solved this problem?**this is my code**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();


    String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");
    String message1 = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    String title1 = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    if (!title.equals("null") && !title.isEmpty()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.khatemsalavet);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    } else {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        intent1.setData(uri);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title1);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message1);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.khatemsalavet);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


    }

}
```

**error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
>                 java.lang.NullPointerException
>                     at com.example.kaveh.khasalavatonline.FcmMessagingService.onMessageReceived(FcmMessagingService.java:32)
>                     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown
>   Source)
>                     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: this code just need a bit of debugging !! and you do need to add `notification channel` to the `notificationManager` incase you are using `API>=26` are you using oreo ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-8-oreo check this out !!

Comment: i several times debug, but I did not understand where the problem  ،i use API18

Comment: debug means ..debug with red dots run the app in debug mode !!

Comment: got it now enjoy !! (do this checking instead of equals use `title !=null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `title !=null` this will solve your issue !!

Comment: are you sending both notification and data messages from cloud functions?

Comment: @SantanuSur Thank you fixed :)))