# error: cannot access zzb class file for com.google.firebase.iid.zzb not found

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, account-kit

Getting error:

> error: cannot access zzb
>   class file for com.google.firebase.iid.zzb not found

after including AccountKit:

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
```

> Also onCreate &  onDestroy is not getting resolved.

```
    public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

     @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    }
```

Firebase & play services: v11.4.0

Comment: I had this error when I added the new Places Implementation, any fix here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Firebase` and `play services` libraries were older. 
Upgraded them to `v15.0.0` and `accountkit` to `v4.32` resolved compile errors and build errors.

- **Update:**
  15.0.0 **crashed** at runtime when notification was received (fortunately app was in beta)
  Stacktrace:
  AbstractMethodError:firebase.iid.zzb.zzd(intent)

**Solution-**
Downgrading them to **11.8.0** worked.
(Accountkit v4.32)

- **Update**: Also faced problem of not receiving push notification on Oreo 8.0

**Solution**- [Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo)