# Notification does not show firebase Android 8

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that is supposed to show a push notification but it doesn't
this line `new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);` is canceled out in the code.
I'm new to this, how can this work
 here is the code in FirebaseMessagingService.java class

```
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String MessageBody){
 Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Hope");
     notificationBuilder.setContentText(MessageBody);
   notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
   notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
  notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

}

}
```

Comment: What way did you use to push notification? from Firebase console or backend service?

Comment: @NhaPhạmThị from firebase console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems duplicate question of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo).

Since **Android O** (It means your targetSdk is 26 or above), notification will not be showing without [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels).

This is my working code :)

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

// The id of the channel.
final String CHANNEL_ID = "default";
// The user-visible name of the channel.
final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Default";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel defaultChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(defaultChannel);
}

intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setLargeIcon(your_custom_bitmap)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(c, R.color.notification))
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
        .setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(c, R.color.colorAccentLight), 5000, 5000)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify("myapp", 0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("", "", 1);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you push notification from Firebase console, you just get notification display if the app is on background or not running. You can read more at [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). If you want to receive notification data on onMessageReceived() method, you have to send the notification from a backend