# FCM push message not receiving in Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented `FCM`. The messages are receiving in `Android N` and lower devices.

---

**dependency**

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
```

I have tried sending messages from `firebase` console. It showing in `Android N` but not in `Android O`.

I have tried sending data notification from the server. Didn't got any call on `onMessageReceived()` in `Android O`.

---

**Added channel while showing notification**

```
 val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "CRW notification channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
```

I have checked this in *`Samsung S2`* and *`One plus 6`*.

Do I need to do anything extra for `Android O` other than setting notification channel on showing the notification?

Comment: have u check this **[Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo)**

Comment: Yes, I have added channel while showing notification.

Comment: Try to send the notification, after auto start on in setting

Comment: I am having this same problem from last 3 days and my FCM messages are received on Android 7 but not on 8

Comment: Any updates on this  @sunsun? Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @Gabbar: It started working now, I still don't know what was wrong then.

Comment: @SunSun can you show here how you have created the message object? I have a question here would be great if you have any knowledge on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571235/cloud-function-fcm-send-error. Thanks

Comment: actually i have same issue on vivo v9..i my device i cant get fcm token.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your FCM to **high-priority**.

Add this to your message body:

```
{
  ...
  "priority":"high"
  ...
}
```

> High priority. FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access). High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: Hi, i have a question here for similar problem, would be great if you can contribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571235/cloud-function-fcm-send-error. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Check this on server side the push message is sent as Data Payload or Notification 
For android version greater than M it requires to send notification in Data Payload 
By passing send Data (on server side).
Also works when app is running in background.

Comment: The notification sent as Data payload. This is working as expected (both background and foreground) in Android L, M, and N.

Comment: Check if this issue only the case in background

Comment: I suggest you to send both notification and data payload 
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}