# Not receiving Cloud function FCM message in android 8

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have below Cloud function to send FCM, it is received successfully in Android 7, but I am not able to get it working in Android 8.

My cloud function lib versions are :

> ```
> "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
> "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2"
> ```

```
var message = { 
                data : {  event: `${constants.NOTIF_EVENT_START_SESSION}` , payload : `${jsonData}`}
            }        
            var options = {
                priority: "high",
                timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
                };
            console.info(`Getting notification token for the user`)  

                const token = 'token_here'
                console.info(`Received notification token for the user ${token}`) 
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, message,options)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.info("Successfully sent notification of start session")
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.warn("Error sending notification of start session: " , error)
                })
```

This is perfectly in Android 7 and below, but this message is not received on Android 8!
So I updated priority like below, as documentation suggests now :

```
    var message = { 
        data : {  event: `${constants.NOTIF_EVENT_START_SESSION}` , payload : `${jsonData}`}
        , android : { priority : "high" }
    }
```

But adding this android -> priority here is giving me error in cloud function like below :

> Error sending notification of start session:  { Error: Messaging
>   payload contains an invalid "android" property. Valid properties are
>   "data" and "notification".
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)

What is going on here!

**Update 1:**

Thanks AL, I have replaced sendToDevice() to send(), and also sending token also along with message object
Result : 
I get this error in cloud function :

> Error sending notification of start session:  { Error: Firebase Cloud
>   Messaging API has not been used in project my_project_id before or it
>   is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/fcm.googleapis.com/overview?project=my_project_id
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

I will update again soon.

**Update 2**

I enabled this API for my project and after waiting for few mins, it has started showing notification in Android 7. But on Android 8, I do not receive FCM message (I have put breakpoint on onMessageReceived but it never gets hit). Below is my service code :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyMessagingService";

    @Inject
    NotificationConstants constants;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupNotificationChannels();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setupNotificationChannels() {
        setupNotificationChannel(constants.SHARE_ID, constants.getShareName());
        setupNotificationChannel(constants.REQUEST_ID, constants.getRequestName());
        setupNotificationChannel(constants.OTHER_ID, constants.getOtherName());
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setupNotificationChannel(String id, String name) {
        NotificationManager mgr = ((NotificationManager) (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)));
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, mgr.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mgr.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    .....
    }
```

Anyone having a clue about what can go wrong?

Comment: The issue here could be in the Android client side. Android 8.0 and above requires a notification channel.

Comment: This is a data FCM message, so 1st step would be Cloud Function sending FCM message, 2nd Step Android App receiving FCM message, 3rd Step Android App showing notification. At the moment it is failing in Step 1) with above invalid 'android' property, if I remove this then still is does not do Step 2)

Comment: First off, you mentioned that the code worked (before adding the priority), *except for Android 8* -- hence my notification channel recommendation. Second, you are using `sendToDevice()`, which is a *Legacy send operation*, which I'm not entirely sure of, but is probably using FCM's legacy API as well. The Platform overrides `android`, `apns`, and `webpush` are all features only available for FCM v1. So you have 2 possible solutions. 1 is revert to your previous payload and implement a notification channel for Android 8 support. 2 is use the `send()` operation in cloud functions.

Comment: Once you tried them out and it didn't work, post updates in your question if there are new errors occurring.

Comment: @AL. I have updated the question, can you help, I am stuck. Cheers

Comment: Sorry just got back with extra time. Looks like you figured it out. Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted after the allotted time. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is how I got it working :

Firebase release notes say : `FirebaseInstanceId` service was deprecated, around 28 June 2018, and my tokens were update in subclass of that service.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

While looking in my database I noticed that my firebase token for Android 7 phone was same, but firebase token for Android 8 phone had changed, but my cloud functions could not pickup latest token as app could not send back updated token.

So I implemented `onNewToken` method of `FirebaseMessagingService` and now my token is updated, and I get FCM messages on Android O.