# Unable to create channel id for local notification Android Oreo version?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app which I have used local notification which is working fine till android version naught but its not showing notification in Android Oreo version. Its ask to create a "channel id " to get the local notification.

So, what's the way to create a channel id used in local notification.

Comment: Have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo

Answer (score 0):

In Oreo version for notification you have to add this in your fcm class(when notification generate)

For  more detail refer :https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

```
val channelId = "Default"
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
```