# Azure NotificationHub push notification doesn't work for Android 8.0 API 26

Tags: android, azure-notificationhub

I implemented **Azure NotificationHub** push notification. I tested for a couple of devices.

It works on these devices:

- Samsung J5 phone Android 7.1.1 (API 25)
- Samsung Tablet A Android 7.1.1 (API 25)

But no push notification is received on a Samsung S9 phone running Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

What could be wrong with the Samsung S9?

Comment: Check if the battery optimization is not allowing the application to run in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Android 8, notification requires a [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) to be shown. The Azure NotificationHub [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started) does not mention NotificationChannels. See also: [Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo)

Comment: What does that mean "a NotificationChannel to be shown"?

Comment: you must create a Notification Channel, otherwise the notification will not be shown