# Notification using beacons not detected in Oreo devices

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, beacon

I am using beacons to display a notification when a beacon is detected. But no notification is displayed in Oreo devices. It works well in devices below Oreo version. 
Should I make changes in the notification section or in the beacon part?

PS : I already know that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo) link has an answer. I just wanted to make sure if the changes must be done in the notification section alone or beacons also play a part in it.

Comment: Please post relevant beacon and notification code, so someone might be able to help

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @SarthakGrover thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make change in the notification display section .

here a sample of code which i used

```
 private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "notification_chanel";// The id of the channel.
        CharSequence name = "App name";// The user-visible name of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notext)
                .setContentTitle("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent).build();

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        return notification;

    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notext)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. But the issue is..the notification is not displayed when the app is killed. What is the solution for that?