# Notifications are not shown on Android 8 and 9

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, notificationmanager

I am developing an `Android` app that includes notifications. I have tried the new `Android 8` notification code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Channel"+notificationId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_logo)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setChannelId("Channel"+notificationId);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel" + notificationId;// The id of the channel.
        CharSequence name = "MyApp";// The user-visible name of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

But still doesn't work and no notifications are shown neither on 8 nor 9.

Comment: Does it work on version older than Oreo? Also, does the application has notifications enabled in settings?

Comment: Yea, it works on Android 7 and 6. Notifications are allowed yes.

Comment: Please follow this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to replace

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

with

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

to make it work.

Comment: Yea, it was really the issue, along with another wrong method call. Thanks