# Android 9 Api 28 Notification not showing

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to show notification but it's not working for both Oreo and Pie version.

It's working in kitkat version.

I tried all the possible condition i can do, i don't know what else i'm missing here

Here is my code:

```
String idChannel = "my_channel_01";
        Intent mainIntent;
        mainIntent = new Intent(ChecklistOptionActivity.this, CashCountOptionActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
        // The id of the channel.

        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bc_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText("Test");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(idChannel, context.getString(R.string.app_name), importance);
            // Configure the notification channel.
            mChannel.setDescription("Test");
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        } else {
            builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBlue))
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250})
                    .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 500, 5000)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
        }
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo)

Answer (score 2):

```
String channel_id = createNotificationChannel(context); 

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id);
```

The below method is to generate a new channel_id.

```
 public static String createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
        
                // NotificationChannels are required for Notifications on O (API 26) and above.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        
                    // The id of the channel.
                    String channelId = "Channel_id";
        
                    // The user-visible name of the channel.
                    CharSequence channelName = "Application_name";
                    // The user-visible description of the channel.
                    String channelDescription = "Application_name Alert";
                    int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                    boolean channelEnableVibrate = true;
        //            int channelLockscreenVisibility = Notification.;
        
                    // Initializes NotificationChannel.
                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);
                    notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(channelEnableVibrate);
        //            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(channelLockscreenVisibility);
        
                    // Adds NotificationChannel to system. Attempting to create an existing notification
                    // channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to perform the
                    // below sequence.
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    assert notificationManager != null;
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        
                    return channelId;
                } else {
                    // Returns null for pre-O (26) devices.
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

- Here, you will get push notification using `channel_id` in your device which is consist 26+ SDK version.
- Because, the `NotificationCompat.Builder(context)` method has been deprecated so that you will have to use an updated method `NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)` which has two parameters one is for context, the second one is for channel_id.
- In the devices which has 26+ SDK version, you can create channel_id every time.

Comment: Yes, This solution is working on my project and any version of the device.

Comment: it's weird that my new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id); only allows context, when i add channel_id it shows an error.

Comment: is your import is android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat? and do you use BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: and use `com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0`