# Notifications are not working anymore. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android

My application implements 5 type of Custom Notifications.
In february, everething worked fine.
I'm now working back on it and there are no Notification displayed anymore.

First, i made a test With firebase cloud messaging. A notificication is successfully shown on my devices.
Then, i tried to modify my code folowing this answer:
[Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo).
Without success.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.philipp.us">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <!-- for android -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->


    <!-- for Samsung -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />

    <!-- for htc -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />

    <!-- for sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />

    <!-- for apex -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />

    <!-- for solid -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />

    <!-- for huawei -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <!-- for ZUK -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" />

    <!-- for OPPO -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <!-- for EvMe -->
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.philipp.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.philipp.android.ConversationActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_item_conversations"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <service android:name="com.example.philipp.android.PushMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.example.philipp.android.PushIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!--
      Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.

        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <!--
         Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming

        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.philipp.android.UserProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_item_userprofile"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.example.philipp.android.GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.my.package.name.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.philipp.android.PushMessagingService$NotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.philipp.android.SubscriptionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_subscription"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my first Custom Notifications:

````
    DataBaseHelper2 dbHelper2;

    File storageDir;
    Context context;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    public PushMessagingService() {
        context = this;
    }

    public static class NotificationID {
        private static final  AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(5);
        public static int getID() {
            return c.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
    public static int notifbadgeCount = 0;

    final String TAG = "PushMessageReceiver";

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        notifbadgeCount++;
        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, notifbadgeCount); //for 1.1.4+

        dbHelper2 = new DataBaseHelper2();
        storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.toString());

        final Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, data.get("message") + " " + data.get("sender") + " " + data.get("sender_id") + " " + data.get("type") + " " + data.get("id") + " " + data.get("photo"));
        int icon = R.drawable._logo_us_without_bkgrdxxxhdpi;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (isRunning(this) && data.get("type").equals("greeting")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GREETING");
        }


//KEYWORD MATCH
        if (data.get("type").equals("question")) {

            Log.d(TAG, "QUESTION");

// Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
//NORMALSIZE
            //Set Notification remote Layout
            RemoteViews notificationLayoutkeywordmatch = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_keywordmatch);
            //User Photo
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_userprofilpic, R.drawable._btn_addprofilpicmdpi);
            //Header
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_applogo, R.drawable._logo_us_without_bkgrdmdpi);
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_app_name, "ask Us");
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setTextViewText(R.id.lbl_date_and_time, DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_notification_type, R.drawable._ic_questionxxxhdpi);
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_arrow_down, R.drawable.simple_arrow_downmdpi);
            //Body
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_keywordmatch_text, getString(R.string.notif_keyword_match));
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_keywordmatch_sender, data.get("sender"));
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatch.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_keywordmatch_question, data.get("message"));

//EXSTENDED SIZE
            //Set Notification remote Layout
            RemoteViews notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_keywordmatchexpanded);
            //User Photo
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_userprofilpic, R.drawable._btn_addprofilpicmdpi);
            //Header
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_applogo, R.drawable._logo_us_without_bkgrdmdpi);
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_app_name, "ask Us");
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.lbl_date_and_time, DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_arrow_up, R.drawable.simple_arrow_upmdpi);
            //Body
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_keywordmatch_text, getString(R.string.notif_keyword_match));
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_notification_type, R.drawable._ic_questionxxxhdpi);
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_keywordmatch_sender, data.get("sender")+ ":");
            notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_keywordmatch_question, data.get("message"));

//Set Notification Channel
            final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int notificationId = 1;
            String channelId = "channel-01";
            String channelName = "Someone could need you";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        channelId, channelName, importance);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }


//Set Pending Intent
            final Intent ii = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ConversationActivity.class);
            ii.putExtra("questionId", data.get("id"));
            ii.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, ii, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Apply the layouts to the notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable._logo_us_without_bkgrdmdpi)
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayoutkeywordmatch)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setChannelId(channelId);

            // Build notification

            final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

            final NotificationTarget notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(context, R.id.img_userprofilpic, notificationLayoutkeywordmatch, notification, 0);
            final NotificationTarget notificationTargetExpanded = new NotificationTarget(context, R.id.img_userprofilpic, notificationLayoutkeywordmatchexpanded, notification, 0);


            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(data.get("photo"))
                            .into(notificationTarget);

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(data.get("photo"))
                            .into(notificationTargetExpanded);
                }
            });


            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);

        }```


Thank you for help.
````

Comment: Have u created notification channels?

Comment: Yes, in the part of the notification code entitled: //Set Notification Channel

Comment: I am investigating this problem but I do not find any solution. There is no error in the logcat neither on Android Studio nor in Firebase. Is there here an expert who could take time to help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

android above oreo will not show the notification in the foreground. You need to show it in the alert dialog