# Time not display on Notification on android 9 and above

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-9.0-pie

I am sending a notification in my app from FCM console and working fine in below android 9 devices, In the above android 9 device Time is not displayed in the notification.

below is my code -

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
             mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setSmallIcon(smallicon)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(colorPrimary)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[0])
            .build();
```

After adding two-parameter to notification compact still not working -

```
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setShowWhen(true)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo)

Comment: Not duplication, in my case notification are displaying but time is not display on it.

Answer (score 0):

use setStyle method,

```
.setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle)
```