# Android Oreo Notification

Tags: java

```
private void showNotification(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
     Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
             .setContentTitle("myApp")
             .setTicker("myApp")
             .setContentText("Application is running")
             .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
             .build();
     // starts this service as foreground
     startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

"Notification" above is not working (OREO)
How can I redesign according to Oreo?
Please help me.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification not showing in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo)

Comment: Turns off immediately after opening as an error