# com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in Android, when it is required

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

Why is the purpose of Android permission "`com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ`".

When this is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for adding the notification counter on the application icon.

[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136483/how-to-interface-with-the-badgeprovider-on-samsung-phones-to-add-a-count-to-the)