# How do I show badge counts on the app icon or in widget

Tags: android, badge

For example: my app got few messages and I need to inform user about this.

Do I need make widget?

I read this [How do I add a number to the launcher icon like HTC mail Does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721119/how-do-i-add-a-number-to-the-launcher-icon-like-htc-mail-does), but it looks like I can't do this. Only for HTC.

Comment: You can inform user using the `Notification` feature of android also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launcher icons as managed by the launcher which the default launcher does not have this functionality.

I would recommend to use the [notification bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and then secondary a possible widget but it wouldn't be required.

As a note, a launcher that does have this functionality is ADW but I don't believe there is an API for it so they would manager which notifications get displayed on which applications.
ADWNotifier: check [**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher.notifications&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Android's user notification design principle revolves around the notification bar. The user should be always alerted only using notifications.