# How to unread count message display in app icon in android

Tags: android

How to implement unread message notification in our app like in messaging (in picture).[image]

how to show number of unread messages in home screen icon. It need to create automatically when install the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show counts on the app icon or in widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273225/how-do-i-show-counts-on-the-app-icon-or-in-widget)

Comment: Android does not use these counts on the icon. If you really must have it try to implement a widget.

Comment: look here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon][1]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Unlike iOS, Android has no concept of icon badges where you can show unread counts and such stuff.

If you really really want it, you'll have to implement a homescreen widget that looks like your launcher icon, and draw your badge over it manually. However, this is not recommended for Android, and having one random app do this may confuse the user.